# Is it possible to get accepted in a PhD program without reference/recommendation letters?

Tags: phd, recommendation-letter

Is it possible to get accepted into a Ph.D. program without reference/recommendation letters?

How likely is it ?

If it is very unlikely, is there any way to get around this unlikeliness?

Comment: Possible, yes.  But unlikely.

Comment: @GEdgar, how unlikely?

Comment: Very, very unlikely.

Comment: which country?~

Comment: For all practical purposes: NO.

Comment: Sure you can - in countries which do not use recommendation letters in the first place.

Comment: I just wonder how many people you need to disappoint or to quarrel with to not be able to request a single recommendation letter. Of course, there are exceptional situations, but normally any professor who taught you a course in which you performed reasonably well would agree to write a few words. Those may be not the *best possible* recommendation letters, but if your transcript is generally good and you are not aiming at Harvard or Princeton, they'll satisfy the formal requirements.

Answer (score 7):

Most admissions committees I know people on will not consider incomplete applications.

If there is an application deadline that applies for an entire incoming class, and letters aren't received, then it's probable that the application will be rejected.

If there is no admissions deadline and If the rest of the application looks good, though, they may contact the applicant to remind them to send in letters so that the application can be considered.

The reason for asking for the letters is a form of quality control: admissions committees want candidates who will become productive researchers. Getting letters of recommendation that can testify to their promise as researchers is an integral part of the admissions process.